# iOS get today's day and month as int

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I'm just learning Objective-C and Xcode and trying to make some simple apps.
I need to get today's day and month as ant int.
Example:
Todays day: 29/12/2013
`(int) TodaysDay = 29;`
`(int) TodaysMonth = 1200;` (1 - 100, 2 - 200, 3 - 300...)
`(int) TodaysValue = TodaysDay + TodaysMonth;` (in ex. 1229)
`switch(TodaysValue)`
`case 1229:`
`do something.`
I tried using this:

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd/MM"];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:today];
```

Thank you for your help!
This works pretty well!

```
CFGregorianDate currentDate = CFAbsoluteTimeGetGregorianDate(CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent(), CFTimeZoneCopySystem());
TodaysDay = currentDate.day;
TodaysMonth = currentDate.month;
TodaysValue = TodaysDay + (TodaysMonth * 100);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lookup the `components:fromDate:` method of `NSCalendar` - this will convert an `NSDate` object to an `NSDateComponents` object correctly, and the latter provides properties for the day and month you require.

Answer (score 0):

After you get dateString, implement following expression as follows to get date and month as integer.

```
 NSArray *date = [dateString componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];
 if ([date count] == 2)
 {
     NSUInteger day = [[date objectAtIndex:0] integerValue];
     NSUInteger month = [[date objectAtIndex:1] integerValue];
 }
```

Comment: Ugh. This is overly complex,and also fragile. Date formats vary based on locale, so parsing the output of a date formatter as a string may break. CRDs recommendation of using NSCalendar and components:fromDate: is a much cleaner, more reliable way to do this.